# Inanimate nouns used in the phrase "want/need somebody to do"

Tags: collocation, phrase-usage, animacy

> I don't need [**this document** ] to contain a disclaimer formulated in such a straightforward way.
>
> I want [**my words or my assertion**] to sound convincing in the meeting tomorrow.

Having done a google search, I came to a conclusion that the above phrasing would be somewhat incorrect.

But I want to make sure of that. Am I right that the structure "want/need somebody to do" does not collocate with inanimate things?

Comment: You are absolutely not right. I can want that telephone box to leap ten feet in the air. It's not going to happen, of course, because it can't do that. But I can want it nonetheless.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? If your statement "Am I right that the structure . . . does not collocate with inanimate things" is permitted, and you seem to use it with a confidence suggesting that it is, why should that "rule" not extend to other inanimate things besides "structure"?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why it might not collocate, in theory; the idea's not silly. But it does collocate, in fact. _Want_ and _need_ (regular, not semi-modal _need_) both take infinitive complements with A-Equi and B-Raising. "A-Equi" means if there's no NP between _want_ or _need_ and the infinitive, the subject of the infinitive is the same as the subject of _want_ or _need_. B-Raising means if there **is** an NP, that NP is the subject of the infinitive instead; and in this case, _to contain_ and _to sound_ are both stative verbs that can take inanimate patient subjects, so no problem.

Comment: [*Einstein **needed the speed of light to be identical both ways** relative to the railwaytrack, but not the train, for this example to work*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wteiuxyqtoM). In fact, all humanity (and probably *everything*) "needs" most universal constants and laws to be pretty much exactly what they are, or nothing could exist in the first place. OP is just getting confused because *"I want **you** to do X"* implies *"I **urge** you to do X"*, but we can't "urge" inanimate "objects" like the speed of light to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both perfectly grammatical and intelligible.  You can "want" (or not want)  or "need" (or not need) anything to happen, regardless whether a person is involved in causing it.